# Is Kafka ready for production use?

Tags: apache-kafka

I have an application in production that has to process several gigabytes of messages per day. I like the Kafka architecture and performance a lot; it perfectly fits my needs.

I'd like to replace my messaging layer with [Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/) at some point. Is the 0.7.1 version good enough for production use in terms of stability and consistency in performance?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is definitely in use at several Big Data companies already, including LinkedIn, where it was created (and later open sourced), and Tumblr.  Just Tumblr by itself handles many gigabytes of messages per day.  I'm sure LinkedIn is way up there too.  You can see a list of companies known to currently use it here:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Powered+By

Also, be sure to subscribe to their mailing list, there are lots of people actively trying it out and using it in production environments.

I'm sure it can handle whatever volume you can throw at it.

Answer (score 10):

There is one critical feature I think Kafka is missing before it is ready for production.

"Flushing messages to disc if the producer can't reach any Kafka broker"
The issue has been filed a long time ago here:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-156

This feature will makes the complete Kafka event pipline even more robust for some use-cases when the producer **always** has to be able to send events. For example when you track pageviews or like-button clicks and you don't want to miss any events, even if all Kafka brokers are unreachable.

Comment: FYI: Looks like this feature has just been fixed in Kafka: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-789

Comment: Nope, I think 789 has been closed since it's a duplicate of https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-156.

Comment: Aha. My bad. Thanks sandris.

Comment: There are other producer libraries that wrap/extend the base producer functionality and can add buffering, however. E.g. Alpakka I believe is one example

Answer (score 3):

I must agree with Dave, Kafka is a good tool but it missing some basic features which some can be done manually but then you need to think what Kafka provide. some missing things are:

- (As Dave said) Flushing messages to disk when the producer fail to send them
- Consumers ability to track which messages were handled (not just consumed) and which wasn't in case of a restart.
- Monitoring - a way to receive the current status of the entities in the system like the current size of the queue in the producer or the write\read pace at the brokers (those can be done but are not part of the tool).

Answer (score 2):

I have used kafka for quite sometime. Using native java and python clients would be preferred.

I had to struggle a lot finding a proper node.js client. literally re-wrote my whole code many a times using different clients as they had lot of bugs.
Finally settled with [franz-kafka](https://github.com/dannycoates/franz-kafka) for node.js.

Apart from that maintaining the consumer offsets is a bit difficult. It is missing some good features like exchanges that exist in AMQP based Apache Qpid or RabbitMQ

Since it's distributed, supports offline messages and the performance is really impressive. I too preferred it :)